# Не открывается `build.gradle` файл котлин

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Наверное только у меня такая проблема, так как в гугле вообще про это ничего не написано.

Все просто , открываю структуру проекта там 2 `build.gradle` файла один апп и другой проект

нажимаю чтоб открыть и не открывается

Причем ни на винде ни на маке

Если работаю с джавой то все ок, в проектах на котлине вот такая ерунда

Подскажите, что это может быть

Comment: 1. Попробуйте очистить кэш: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and restart`
2. Импортировать проект с помощью gradle: `File -> New -> Import Project...` и выбрать корневой `build.gradle`

Comment: @v.andrikeev не, не помагло... Очень странно конечно. Приходиться открывать этот файл через другой ридер. В моем случае Notepad++ , но это не удобно конечно

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант посмотреть разрешения на файл

*Перед всеми советами, сделай бэкап проекта.*

Посмотреть в новых приложениях открывается или нет.
Если открывается, то попробовать удалить все файлы в проекте кроме самих исходников, пересоздать проект и импортировать исходники.
Если нет, то попробуй пере установить android studio (intellij idea), у меня все тормозило и медленно запускалось. Настал момент когда windows стал мне не нужен и я пере разметил жесткий диск под линукс и установил все программы заново. После этого стало меньше ошибок и быстро работать. После удаления нужно также удалить настройки ide.

Comment: Я не думаю, что в этом проблема... Мне кажется это баг самой студии. Этот файл не открывается ни в каких проектах, ни в новых ни в тех которые я скачиваю с гита. Кроме того, у меня есть мак и есть винда ни на маке ни на винде это не открывается...